# Поиск файлов и каталогов не видит AppData

Tags: c++, winapi

Я написал функцию для поиска каталогов, но он не отображал мне папку AppData, тогда я попробовал вывести её как скрытую и системную но ничего не вышло. Почему я не могу её отобразить?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

bool find(std::string path)
{
    std::string ppath = path + "\\*";
    WIN32_FIND_DATAA winFD;
    HANDLE hFile = FindFirstFileA(ppath.c_str(), &winFD);
    if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        while (FindNextFileA(hFile, &winFD))
        {
            if (winFD.dwFileAttributes == FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
            {
                std::cout << "DIRECTORY: " << path + "\\" + winFD.cFileName << std::endl;
            }
            if (winFD.dwFileAttributes == FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN)
            {
                std::cout << "HIDDEN: " << path + "\\" + winFD.cFileName << std::endl;
            }
            if (winFD.dwFileAttributes == FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM)
            {
                std::cout << "SYSTEM: " << path + "\\" + winFD.cFileName << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
    FindClose(hFile);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    find("C:\\Users\\User");
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dwFileAttributes` в `WIN32_FIND_DATAA` — это битовая маска. т.е. если, например, каталог является скрытым и системным, то его значение будет побитовой дизъюнкцией соответствующих констант:

```
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM
```

Соответственно и проверять это значение нужно с помощью побитового И:

```
if (winFD.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) {
  std::cout << "DIRECTORY: " << path + "\\" + winFD.cFileName;
}
if (winFD.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN) {
   std::cout << "[hidden]";
}
std::cout << std::endl;
```